# Can create object by special Array string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, object, reduce

I have a string array:

```
["action=order_changed", "orderId=10002701", "brandId=5983e481fab80f4198691bbc", "unitId=5e801b6ddd43bb20cc2e5469", "isRepeat=false", "isDisplay=true"]
```

I want to create an object from it by split `=` foreach item from Array.

My expected object is:

```
{
    action: "order_changed",
    orderId: 10002701,
    brandId: "5983e481fab80f4198691bbc",
    unitId: "5e801b6ddd43bb20cc2e5469",
    isRepeat: false,
    isDisplay: true
}
```

I have using foreach, not practice with reduce much so my code is bad.

```js
splitStringParameter(str: string) {
  let stringQuery = str.split('?').pop(); 
  let arrayQuery = stringQuery.split('&'); 
  let object = {}; 
  arrayQuery.forEach(item => {
    item.split("="); 
    object[item[0]] = item[1]
  })
}
```

Thanks so much

Comment: is order_changed a string or a variable name?

Comment: it's string :D thanks for help

Comment: Updated my answer @phúphạm, now that I understand the initial input was a query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split key and value using `String.split` and join them into a new object using `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
const input = ["action=order_changed", "orderId=10002701", "brandId=5983e481fab80f4198691bbc", "unitId=5e801b6ddd43bb20cc2e5469", "isRepeat=false", "isDisplay=true"];

const output = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const curArr = cur.split("=");
  const key = curArr[0];
  const value = curArr.splice(1).join("=");
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** (now that you provided code):

Looks like your initial input was a query string - check out [URLSearchParams (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

> ```
> var paramsString = "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api";
> var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
>
> //Iterate the search parameters.
> for (let p of searchParams) {
>   console.log(p);
> }
>
> searchParams.has("topic") === true; // true
> searchParams.get("topic") === "api"; // true
> searchParams.getAll("topic"); // ["api"]
> searchParams.get("foo") === null; // true
> searchParams.append("topic", "webdev");
> searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=api&topic=webdev"
> searchParams.set("topic", "More webdev");
> searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams&topic=More+webdev"
> searchParams.delete("topic");
> searchParams.toString(); // "q=URLUtils.searchParams"
> ```

---

```js
const a = ["action=order_changed", "orderId=10002701", "brandId=5983e481fab80f4198691bbc", "unitId=5e801b6ddd43bb20cc2e5469", "isRepeat=false", "isDisplay=true"];

const transform = v => {
  if (v === 'false') {
    return false;
  }
  if (v === 'true') {
    return true;
  }
  
  return v;
}

const o = a.reduce((res, e) => {
  const [key, val] = e.split('=');
  res[key] = transform(val);

  return res;
}, {});

console.log(o);
```

Comment: @phúphạm code goes [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64691312/edit), not in the comments

Comment: This won't turn `"true"` and `"false"` into Boolean values unfortunately

Comment: @Phil good catch. Added a `transform` that handles Booleans. Integers are more difficult.

Comment: yeah, so i ask the ways to fix it. and it sloved. thanks you :D

Comment: Great I’m glad you solved it! Do you want to accept one of the answers then?